# Removing Parameters from where clause to display records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have a real estate website where people can search property based on Location, Property Type and Builder.

I have a Table like below.

```
CREATE TABLE Project(ProjectId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                     Location  VARCHAR(255), 
                     PropertyType VARCHAR(255), 
                     Builder VARCHAR(255), 
                     ProjectName  VARCHAR(255),
                     Status TINYINT)


INSERT INTO Project(Location, PropertyType, Builder, ProjectName)
             VALUES('Location A', 'Flats',     'Builder A', 'Project A', 1),
                   ('Location A', 'Villas',    'Builder B', 'Project B', 1),
                   ('Location B', 'Flats',     'Builder A', 'Project C', 1),
                   ('Location C', 'Villas',    'Builder C', 'Project D', 1),
                   ('Location B', 'Plots',     'Builder B', 'Project E', 1),
                   ('Location A', 'Row House', 'Builder C', 'Project F', 1),
                   ('Location A', 'Plots',     'Builder A', 'Project G', 1),
                   ('Location C', 'Plots',     'Builder C', 'Project H', 1),
                   ('Location C', 'Flats',     'Builder B', 'Project I', 1),
                   ('Location C', 'Villas',    'Builder B', 'Project J', 1),
                   ('Location A', 'Villas',    'Builder A', 'Project K', 1),
                   ('Location C', 'Flats',     'Builder B', 'Project L', 1);
```

The search procedure which I use is in such a way that It brings back search result as per the parameters they selected i.e Property Type, Location, Builder Name

Now there may be projects for some search parameters as below

Flats by Builder A at Location C

I want to change procedure in such a way the parameters in filters in where clause should change to bring result all the time by considering other possibilities like for the above

Flats by Builder A at Location C

There is no Flats by Builder A at Location C so it should display Flats at Location C by Other Builders

```
      Location C   Flats     Builder B    Project I
```

The Filter should Consider  PropertyType, Location and Builder Name

Villas at Location B

There is No Villas at Location B So

```
Location A    Villas   Builder B   Project B
Location C    Villas   Builder B   Project J
Location A    Villas   Builder A   Project K
```

The search should happen by

```
       PropertyType -> Location -> Builder
```

If there is No project for a particular Builder in that Location then

```
       PropertyType -> Location
```

If there is No project for a particular Location then

```
       PropertyType
```

The parameters in the filters should be eliminated in such a way it brings similar result to search param.

```
       PropertyType -> Location -> Builder       No Records
       PropertyType -> Location                  No Records
       PropertyType                              Records Found
```

The procedure I created is as Below

```
    DROP PROCEDURE  IF EXISTS getProjectResult;
    CREATE PROCEDURE getProjectResult(IN PropertyType VARCHAR(255), IN Location VARCHAR(255), IN BuilderName VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN
      SET @strSQL = 'SELECT * 
                       FROM project
                      WHERE status = 1 ';

      IF PropertyType != '' THEN
        SET @strSQL = CONCAT(@strSQL, ' AND PropertyType ="', PropertyType, '" ');
      END IF;

      IF Location != '' THEN    
        SET @strSQL = CONCAT(@strSQL, ' AND Location ="', Location, '" ');
      END IF;

      IF BuilderName != '' THEN
        SET @strSQL = CONCAT(@strSQL, ' AND Builder ="', BuilderName, '" ');
      END IF;

      PREPARE stmt FROM @strSQL;
      EXECUTE stmt;  
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
    END;
```

So My Procedure is Going to bring output as below

```
     CALL getProjectResult('Flats', 'Location C', 'Builder A');
```

No Output

So it should display

```
       Location C    Flats     Builder B   Project L
```

How to Change Procedure in such a way it remove parameters from filters so it brings result.
The parameters should be removed in following order builder, location and property type.

Property type should be given highest preference followed Location and builder name

Thanks for Reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to do queries like this with a cumulative score, e.g.:

```
 select project_id,
   case when location = ? then 1 else 0 end +
   case when flats = ? then 1 else 0 end + 
   case when builder = ? then 1 else 0 end as score
from project
order by score desc
```

Note that you can also weight them differently with this mechanism (location may be more important than builder, etc.).

And some info you didn't ask for:

- you should better normalize your schema, e.g. don't repeat data.
- you can do fielded searches in text tools like solr as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alian Colins is right , Though if you are not looking for performance side:
Then simple answer to you question is:

```
Alter PROCEDURE getProjectResult  
(@PropertyType as VARCHAR(255), @Location as VARCHAR(255), @BuilderName as VARCHAR(255))
as
BEGIN
  declare @strSQL as varchar(max)
  declare @wherequery as varchar(max)
  SET @strSQL = 'SELECT * 
                   FROM project
                  WHERE status = 1 ';
    set @wherequery = ''
  IF @PropertyType <> '' 
  begin
    SET @wherequery += ' AND (PropertyType ='''+ @PropertyType+ ''' '
  END

  IF @Location <> '' 
  begin
    SET @wherequery += ' AND Location ='''+ @Location+ ''' )'
  END

  IF @BuilderName <> ''
  begin
    SET @wherequery += ' or( Builder ='''+@BuilderName+'''    ' + @wherequery+ ')'
  END

set @strSQL = @strSQL + @wherequery
print @strSQL
  exec(@strSQL)

END
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. Any way how to remove the parameters from where clause so I might get possible records.you added or to builder but what if i dont have property type at that particular location

Comment: you can do same for the location and propertytype..
by adding or like
 SET @wherequery += ' or (Location ='''+ @Location+ ''' and PropertyType= '+@PropertyType +' )'

Comment: I think my question is not clear. Even if I supply three parameters there may or may not be records for the supplied parameters.So if i supply CALL getProjectResult('Villas', 'Location C', 'Builder A') the parameter is not empty but it may or may not have records matching the parameter

Comment: If i use or its going to bring records which matches exactly to parameter along with those which are similar to the search parameter based on precedence

Comment: You should manipulate the where parameters as i have shown you an example..
If you dont have an propertytype param then dont append that column in to your wherequery variable ..

Comment: Or else you need to count the selected rows one by one from where clause and filter accordingly 
Using @@rowcount